# Asynchronously open page in SWT Browser

Tags: java, swt

I have an SWT application that is using theSWT `Browser` class, like this:

```
Browser browser = new Browser(parent, SWT.NONE);
browser.setUrl(myURL);
```

When a big page is loading it blocks the UI because it is running on the same thread, is there any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

`Display.asyncExec` always runs the `Runnable` in the UI thread. It is only useful for running UI code from a background thread, so it won't help you here.

There is no way to load UI code in the background.